# bypass overflow:hidden position:relative of layout ancestor

Tags: css

There is a layout, which I can't change.
It has position:relative,  overflow:hidden.

and there is a component which opens a little window next to it if a button clicked.  **(the component is a deep child of the layout div)**

the layout properties make the window look cut off.

Anything I can do about it?

(I've read some solutions but they require a lot of changes to the layout, and a lot of components relay on that layout)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can override an ancestor's `overflow: hidden` or `position: relative` declarations.

Comment: Need CSS and HTML read about [mcve]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS transform.

```css
.scope {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff0000;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.breakout {
  position: fixed;
  top:-50px;
  right:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scope">
  <div class="overflow-hidden">
    <img class="breakout" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  </div>
</div>
```